# How can I upload a file via ASP.NET MVC and show a progress bar?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, upload, progress-bar

I'm looking to allow a user to browse and upload a file to the server in my ASP.NET MVC application.

If it is possible, I'm interested in adding a progress bar to show how much of the file has been uploaded.

Does anyone have any examples of something like this?  Should I use jQuery to do this?

Comment: try this one [Ajax Multiple file upload script with Progress bar, Drag and Drop qq.FileUploader in mvc 4 razor](http://lesson8.blogspot.com/2012/09/ajax-multiple-file-upload-script-with.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The beauty of ASP.NET MVC is that you can choose almost any out of the box upload component out there and use it without any problems.

This plugin for jQuery is a great choice and one that I use in my projects:
[Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)

Comment: How were you able to get Uploadify to work without a Flash dependency?

Comment: Just removed Uploadify from a project. Flash is getting phased out. A progress bar is not worth your app not working in lots of browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Steve Sanderson put some examples on his [blog](http://blog.codeville.net/2008/11/24/jquery-ajax-uploader-plugin-with-progress-bar/) awhile back that I found helpful.  He has the source code available as well.

Answer (score 1):

Uploadify is nice, but we can't use Flash, so we are using Darren Johnstone's file upload control:

**ASP.Net File Upload/Download Module Version 2**
http://darrenjohnstone.net/2008/07/15/aspnet-file-upload-module-version-2-beta-1/

It includes a progress bar dialog driven entirely with Javascript, and even has the capability to upload and download files directly to a SQL Server database.

Comment: Are you using this upload control in an MVC application? If so, would you mind posting a code snippet on how to get it working?

Comment: We haven't implemented it yet, sorry.

Comment: Dead URL; is there a handy replacement?

Comment: Found this on SourceForge, but there are no files to download for the project: sourceforge.net/projects/fileuploadmod